# How to print only the name of 2 persons with the same name using DISTINCT, but while checking the persons's birth? SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

It works if I do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, birth
FROM people
WHERE name = "x";
```

The only problem is that it also prints the birth.

Comment: wrap it around another select: `select name from (select distinct....) a`

Comment: but couldn't there be two different people have the same name and share the same birthday , even when they are unrelated. weird things a happen some names a common and birthdays are also not that much, only when you have something unique like email addresses for example you could say that they might be different persons

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. It's not very clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM people
GROUP BY name, birth
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for peole with the same name and different birthdates, youn can use

```
SELECT name 
FROM people 
WHERE name = "x"
GROUP BY name
HAVIND COUNT(DISTINCT birth) > 1;
```